# Fastest way to run ridge regression on large datasets where n>>p

Tags: lasso, ridge-regression, glmnet, elastic-net

Provided that you don't want to do any variable selection:

**Is there any software which is faster than `glmnet` at *vanilla ridge regression* for large datasets?**

Comment: what are n and p?

Comment: N in the hundreds of thousands, p in the 100-1000 range. Not sparse.

Comment: sorry, I meant what do the symbols represent (different fields use different symbols)

Comment: N is rows. p is columns.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software.

Answer (score 3):

glmnet is an R package that will end up calling linear algebra routines from the BLAS and LAPACK libraries to do the actual computations.  These library routines can be optimized for a particular computer processor and parallelized to run on multiple processors and they can even be run on GPGPU accelerators to get improved performance.  The first thing to do is to check your installation of R and the BLAS/LAPACK libraries that it is using.  Chances are that you're using BLAS/LAPACK libraries that have not been optimized for performance.

Unfortunately, building software to use optimized BLAS/LAPACK libraries is not a very easy process for most users.  My advice would be to find someone who has experience with optimized linear algebra libraries to help you get your R setup configured to use optimized libraries.

Comment: I'm not wedded to R, it just seems like glmnet legitimately is the fastest regularized regression package I've seen out there because it's coded in FORTRAN. I'm actually fairly eager to not use R.

Comment: For simple ridge regression you don't need anything as fancy as glmnet.  You really just need a fast linear least squares solver.

Comment: Really? You'd think that cross-validation over lambda would be relatively involved.

Comment: THe quickest way to do this is to use the Cholesky factorization of $X^{T}X+\lambda I$ for each value of $\lambda$.  Since the $X^{T}X$ matrix is of size $p$ by $p$, and the matrix should be reasonably conditioned ($\lambda$ needs to be large enough to keep the matrix reasonably conditioned, or else the ridge regression isn't reducing the instability in the least squares problem.)  Computing the Cholesky factorization of a 1,000 by 1,000 matrix can easily be done in less than a second, so the time per value of $\lambda$ is less than a second.

Comment: To make sure that R is using multithreaded matrix operations, e.g. using the Intel MKL libraries, just install Microsoft Open R, or else just overwrite the Rblas.dll and Rlapack.dll files in your R-3.3.3/bin/x64 directory with the Intel MKL ones, https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4dttvsnr3m00kh/Rblas_MKL.zip?dl=0