# Is it statistically sound to use Lasso for variable selection even when $n\gg p$?

Tags: classification, model-selection, lasso

I have a classification task where $n\gg p$ (like 440000 vs. 23). I want to use Lasso (`glmnet` in R) to select the variables first, then use techniques like random forest or boosting for the actual classification. I read this from [*Statistics for High-Dimensional Data: Methods, Theory and Applications*](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-20192-9):

[image]

I am not sure whether Lasso will still do variable selection when $n\gg p$.
Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Why should there be a problem? $n << p$ is the difficult case, your $n >> p$ is the easy case ... so what works in the difficult case should work in the easy case too ...

Comment: When n >> p then you may not need variable selection at all, but if you do decide to use a method, lasso should be fine.

Comment: Some distinct similarities (and seemingly the same misunderstanding about the roles of $n$ and $p$ [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83272/fastest-way-to-run-ridge-regression-on-large-datasets-where-np))

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I mean if the true model is sparse and $p\gg n$, Lasso will select the variables (under some conditions). But if $n \gg p$, can Lasso screen out the insignificant variables?

Comment: @PeterFlom I want to do some variable selection first because the current data frame is too large for some boosting methods.

Comment: It would be useful to ascertain whether any variable selection method, including the lasso, can reliably find a set of predictors.  Simulation may be best for this, but you can try splitting your data in half and running lasso twice.  If there is not substantial overlap in the set of selected variables, beware.

Comment: If the data frame is too large I would take a subset of the observations, not the variables.

Comment: Look her: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2013/05/hastie-glmnet.html  specifically:  "Although Professor Hastie’s presentation was primarily concerned with fitting models for the wide problem (the number of explanatory variables is much larger than the number of observations) the lasso and elastic-net algorithms are just as applicable to data sets with large numbers of observations. "

Comment: Variable set selected for one method may not be the best for the other method, so this two stage approach seems unreliable. Why don't you let random forests or boosting select variables for itself?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Now I can understand. If one thinks forward/backward selection or stagewise regression is reasonable for any data set, the same reason should also hold for LARS/Lasso.

Comment: @user27493 But are the selected variables reflect the physical connections? Say, if you add the constellations (in the sense of astrology) as a predictor for diabetic prediction, it should not be selected by any method.

Comment: @ziyuang There always can be a coincidental correlation, no guarantee against that. No statistical method alone can prove physical connection, it can only give some evidence for or against such connection.